# Fetching FB user-id returns incorrect value ("1")

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a very strange problem:
Sometimes (but not every time!) when I try to get the current user facebook ID, I get "1";
for example:
    $config = array();

```
$config["appId"] = API_KEY;
$config["secret"] = SECRET;
$facebook=  new Facebook($config);
$user=$facbook->getUser();
echo $user['id'];//returns 1;
```

Obviously - this it not the real user ID.
When I check if the access token is still good -I see that it is still valid. Also, even if I force the user to login again using:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        top.location.href="<?php echo HOME_URL;?>"
    }, {scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

Still getting the same result.
Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Hey, `$facebook->getUser()` returns integral facebook Id itself, I don't think there is any 'id' index of the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should ONLY get an ID back from FB:

```
$user_id = $facbook->getUser();
echo $user_id;
```

You would later have to query the API for a user profile (which is what it looks like you are doing):

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

**Reference:**

- http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/